# Specflow BeforeScenario method loops

Tags: c#, automation, specflow

I have code that is something llike this:

```
 public class SBase
    {
        protected IWebDriver driver;
        [BeforeScenario()]
        public void SetUp() {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://abcd.com");
            
        }

        [AfterScenario()]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
```

I don't know why but when I run a test this happens: once the `SetUp()` method finishes, then the `SetUp()` method starts again and again without starting in the first step of the test.

Comment: is your class `SBase` inherited by every step class in your project? I'm assuming so, and that is almost certainly the problem. Don't have steps in classes which are inherited, it causes them to be duplicated

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[TestFixture]
public class SBase
{
protected IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://abcd.com");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        if (driver != null)
            driver.Quit();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
    }
}
```

Try this

Comment: Yes! It was all a problem of inheritance.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this. This is a recipe for future issues as specflow is no longer responsible for the test initialisation